# json string cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to get parse `Json` string in my android application but I am getting the below exception. Please help

**Exception**:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value 
{
    "DateTime": "20 06 2014",
    "Response": null,
    "hoursLeft": 0,
    "token": null,
    "Error": null,
    "IsTrialExpired": false
}
```

of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

**Code**:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s); // I get exception in this line                
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch)).setText(jsonObject.getString("DateTime"));
```

Comment: What is the value of s?

Comment: @GiruBhai The value is in the error-message

Comment: I guess that the parser can't handle the `null`-value?

Comment: try returning empty instead of null

Comment: is "Value" part of your json string?

Comment: Two things. Are you getting this string from a url/web service? If so make sure the encoding is UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1. Also, surround the creation of the json object with a try block so we can see the full exception. Android should be able to handle 'null' just fine. The only exception happens when you try a getString or getANYTYPE against it. Not when you instantiate the JSONObject.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this from WCF rest service. 

And about the encoding I am not very sure what it is right now. 

I have the code block surrounded by try catch block just did not post that here.

Comment: @jcaruso, I will try to replace null with blank string and then try to parse the string

Comment: I tried to pass blank values instead of null but still getting the same exception.

org.json.JSONException: Value {"DateTime":"24 06 2014","Response":"","hoursLeft":0,"token":"","Error":"","IsTrialExpired":false} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your help :)

but I have solved the above issue finally.

The problem was with the format of the string `\"` which I was trying to return from server.

Invalid string

`"{\"Response\":\"6\/24\/2014 5:33:35 PM\",\"hoursLeft\":0,\"token\":\"\",\"Error\":\"\",\"IsTrialExpired\":false}"`

Valid string

`{"DateTime":"24\/06\/2014","Error":"","IsTrialExpired":false,"Response":"","hoursLeft":0,"token":""}`

on the server side I was manually converting the object into json and returning it and this was causing the issue. I just used the `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` in my WCF operation contract and it solved the issue.